# How to get the pointer address of A[i][j] using pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If I declare an array in C: `int B[4];` then I can get the pointer to address of `B[2]` by: `&B[2]` or `B+2`.

But say I declared the 2-dimensional array `A[3][6]` how would I access a particular pointer in the array for `A[i][j]` using pointer arithmetic and not `&A[i][j]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by an example:

```
int A[3][6];
int i = 2;
int j = 4;
int* p = A[i]+j;
```

Of course, since any array is a consecutive piece of memory (consisting of 18 `int` elements in the example above), you can also cast it into a simple pointer, and then refer to whichever element you want.

For example:

```
int* p = (int*)A+i*6+j;
```

You can compute the exact number of columns (6 in the example above), using any of the following:

- `sizeof(*A)/sizeof(**A)`
- `sizeof(A[0])/sizeof(A[0][0])`
- `sizeof(A[x])/sizeof(A[y][z]) // x,y,z are any integer constants or variables`

But you can do so safely **only** within the array's scope of declaration (function if it's a local variable, or file if it's a global variable).

Comment: This indeed works and is close to what I'm after. What confuses me is how the compiler evaluates A[i]+j. In your example you have i = 2 and j = 4. So this is valid C: p = A[2] + 4, but my understanding is that A[2]is equivalent to A + 2 so I thought that A[2]+4 == A + 6 but it isn't...

Comment: @James Clark: As long as you do it **within the array's scope of declaration** (`p = A[2] + 4` in your example), the compiler can translate the indexing precisely.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that in C, `A[i]` is exactly equivalent to `*(A + i)`.<sup>1</sup> Apply that rule recursively, and you're done.

---

<sub>1. Actually, it's equivalent to `(*((A) + (i)))`, but that's harder to read...</sub>

Comment: but how would that look for A[i][j]?

Comment: A[i] is equivalent to *(A + sizeof(int)*i) not *(A + i) .

Comment: @alireza_fn: No it isn't.  Try it!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: suppose A is 100 and i is 3 so A[i] should be at 103 or 112?

Comment: @alireza_fn:  112 (for 4-byte int).  But again, try running a short example.

Comment: I tried and it seems that you are right but why this happens ? isn't A+sizeof(int)*i equal to 112 in the example ?

Comment: @alireza_fn: Pointer arithmetic is done in *units of the size of the underlying type*.  Otherwise it would make things like `int *p = A; p++;` useless.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a blow by blow illustration of what you want to do.

```
int A[3][6];
int (*pointer_to_row_i_of_A)[6] = A + i;
int *row_i_of_A = *pointer_to_row_i_of_A;
int *pointer_to_row_i_column_j_of_A = row_i_of_A + j;
```

Since an array object when used in an expression like this degrades to the value of the address of its first element, dereferencing a pointer to an array works as illustrated above. As alluded to in [Oli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23447124/315052), you can simplify it into a single expression by removing the temporaries in the illustration above.

```
int *pointer_to_row_i_column_j_of_A = *(A + i) + j;
```